# How to get Readline support in IRB using RVM on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, readline, libreadline

I have tried everything I can think of to get this to work, to no avail so here I am requesting suggestions on how to debug.

Firstly, runnning Ubuntu 11.10

Installed rvm:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
```

Installed readline using apt-get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
```

Check for readline install:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep readline
lib64readline-gplv2-dev             install
lib64readline5                  install
libreadline-dev                 install
libreadline5                    install
libreadline6                    install
libreadline6-dev                install
readline-common                 install
```

Install ruby, with readline support?

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=/usr
```

Here is rvm version:

```
$ rvm --version

rvm 1.9.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Lets try the ruby shell:

```
$ irb
1.9.2 :001 > puts "add history"
add history
 => nil 
1.9.2 :002 > ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A <------ PRESS UP ARROW DOES THIS
```

No, ok so if its not going to work with ubuntu's readline version??? lets try with rvm's own version of readline:

```
$ rvm pkg install readline
Fetching readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1989k  100 1989k    0     0   318k      0  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--  418k
Extracting readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/keith/.rvm/patches/readline-5.2/shobj-conf.patch'...
Prepare readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
ERROR: Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/keith/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Compiling readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Installing readline to /home/keith/.rvm/usr
Fetching readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2224k  100 2224k    0     0   310k      0  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--  444k
Extracting readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/keith/.rvm/patches/readline-6.2/patch-shobj-conf.diff'...
Prepare readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
ERROR: Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/keith/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Compiling readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Installing readline to /home/keith/.rvm/usr
```

Ok, there's an error there, lets take a look:

```
$ more /home/keith/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
[2011-11-17 22:31:15] autoreconf -is --force
autoheader: warning: missing template: CTYPE_NON_ASCII
autoheader: Use AC_DEFINE([CTYPE_NON_ASCII], [], [Description])
autoheader: warning: missing template: FIONREAD_IN_SYS_IOCTL
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_BSD_SIGNALS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_GETPW_DECLS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_LANGINFO_CODESET
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_MBRLEN
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_MBSCMP
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_MBSNRTOWCS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_MBSRTOWCS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_MBSTATE_T
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_POSIX_SIGNALS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_POSIX_SIGSETJMP
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_FILENO
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_STRUCT_DIRENT_D_INO
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_USG_SIGHOLD
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_WCRTOMB
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_WCSCOLL
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_WCSDUP
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_WCTYPE
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_WCWIDTH
autoheader: warning: missing template: MUST_REINSTALL_SIGHANDLERS
autoheader: warning: missing template: NO_MULTIBYTE_SUPPORT
autoheader: warning: missing template: SPEED_T_IN_SYS_TYPES
autoheader: warning: missing template: STRCOLL_BROKEN
autoheader: warning: missing template: STRUCT_WINSIZE_IN_SYS_IOCTL
autoheader: warning: missing template: STRUCT_WINSIZE_IN_TERMIOS
autoheader: warning: missing template: TIOCSTAT_IN_SYS_IOCTL
autoheader: warning: missing template: VOID_SIGHANDLER
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoheader failed with exit status: 1
```

And as expected irb isn't working with readline:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=\$HOME/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p352 to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracted to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
Applying patch 'stdout-rouge-fix' (located at /home/keith/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch)
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #importing default gemsets (/home/keith/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #complete 
$ irb
Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.
You may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries.
1.8.7 :001 >
```

Have I installed all the rvm requirements? Yes here look:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
autoconf is already the newest version.
automake is already the newest version.
bison is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
git-core is already the newest version.
libc6-dev is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
libreadline6 is already the newest version.
libreadline6-dev is already the newest version.
libreadline6-dev set to manually installed.
libsqlite3-0 is already the newest version.
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
libtool is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
libyaml-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
sqlite3 is already the newest version.
subversion is already the newest version.
zlib1g is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And so it goes on, and on and on and on.....

```
$ rvm remove 1.8.7
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 binaries...

$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=\$HOME/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p352 to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracted to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
Applying patch 'stdout-rouge-fix' (located at /home/keith/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch)
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #importing default gemsets (/home/keith/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #complete 

$ irb
Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.
You may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries.
1.8.7 :001 > 

$ cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352/ext/readline/
$ ruby extconf.rb 
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_filename_completion_function()... yes
checking for rl_username_completion_function()... yes
checking for rl_completion_matches()... yes
checking for rl_deprep_term_function in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_append_character in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_attempted_completion_over in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_library_version in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_event_hook in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_cleanup_after_signal()... yes
checking for rl_clear_signals()... yes
checking for rl_vi_editing_mode()... yes
checking for rl_emacs_editing_mode()... yes
checking for replace_history_entry()... yes
checking for remove_history()... yes
creating Makefile

$ make
gcc -shared -o readline.so readline.o -L. -L/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -Wl,-R/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -L/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -lruby -lreadline -lncurses  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc

$ make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 readline.so /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-linux

$ rvm remove 1.8.7
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 binaries...

$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=\$HOME/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p352 to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracted to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
Applying patch 'stdout-rouge-fix' (located at /home/keith/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch)
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #importing default gemsets (/home/keith/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #complete 

$ irb
Readline was unable to be required, if you need completion or history install readline then reinstall the ruby.
You may follow 'rvm notes' for dependencies and/or read the docs page https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ . Be sure you 'rvm remove X ; rvm install X' to re-compile your ruby with readline support after obtaining the readline libraries.
1.8.7 :001 > $ 

$ rvm pkg install readline
Fetching readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/archives
Extracting readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/keith/.rvm/patches/readline-5.2/shobj-conf.patch'...
Prepare readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
ERROR: Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/keith/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Compiling readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Installing readline to /home/keith/.rvm/usr
Fetching readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/archives
Extracting readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/keith/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/keith/.rvm/patches/readline-6.2/patch-shobj-conf.diff'...
Prepare readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
ERROR: Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/keith/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Compiling readline in /home/keith/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Installing readline to /home/keith/.rvm/usr

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxslt1-dev' instead of 'libxslt-dev'
Note, selecting 'libncurses5-dev' instead of 'ncurses-dev'
autoconf is already the newest version.
automake is already the newest version.
bison is already the newest version.
build-essential is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
git-core is already the newest version.
libc6-dev is already the newest version.
libncurses5-dev is already the newest version.
libreadline6 is already the newest version.
libreadline6-dev is already the newest version.
libreadline6-dev set to manually installed.
libsqlite3-0 is already the newest version.
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version.
libssl-dev is already the newest version.
libtool is already the newest version.
libxml2-dev is already the newest version.
libxslt1-dev is already the newest version.
libyaml-dev is already the newest version.
openssl is already the newest version.
sqlite3 is already the newest version.
subversion is already the newest version.
zlib1g is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352/ext/readline/

$ ruby extconf.rb --with-readline-dir=/usr
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_filename_completion_function()... yes
checking for rl_username_completion_function()... yes
checking for rl_completion_matches()... yes
checking for rl_deprep_term_function in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_append_character in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_attempted_completion_over in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_library_version in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_event_hook in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_cleanup_after_signal()... yes
checking for rl_clear_signals()... yes
checking for rl_vi_editing_mode()... yes
checking for rl_emacs_editing_mode()... yes
checking for replace_history_entry()... yes
checking for remove_history()... yes
creating Makefile

$ make
gcc -I. -I. -I/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-linux -I. -DHAVE_READLINE_READLINE_H -DHAVE_READLINE_HISTORY_H -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_USERNAME_COMPLETION_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_MATCHES -DHAVE_RL_DEPREP_TERM_FUNCTION -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETION_APPEND_CHARACTER -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_WORD_BREAK_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_BASIC_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_COMPLETER_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_FILENAME_QUOTE_CHARACTERS -DHAVE_RL_ATTEMPTED_COMPLETION_OVER -DHAVE_RL_LIBRARY_VERSION -DHAVE_RL_EVENT_HOOK -DHAVE_RL_CLEANUP_AFTER_SIGNAL -DHAVE_RL_CLEAR_SIGNALS -DHAVE_RL_VI_EDITING_MODE -DHAVE_RL_EMACS_EDITING_MODE -DHAVE_REPLACE_HISTORY_ENTRY -DHAVE_REMOVE_HISTORY -I/usr/include  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -g -O2  -fPIC   -c readline.c
gcc -shared -o readline.so readline.o -L. -L/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -Wl,-R/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -Wl,-R -Wl,/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -L/home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib -lruby -lreadline -lncurses  -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc

$ make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 readline.so /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/i686-linux

$ irb
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :001 > p 1
1
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 :002 > $   

$ rvm remove 1.8.7
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
Removing /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 aliases...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 wrappers...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 environments...
Removing ruby-1.8.7-p352 binaries...

$ rvm install 1.8.7 --with-readline-dir=/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/keith/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #fetching 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracting ruby-1.8.7-p352 to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #extracted to /home/keith/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p352
Applying patch 'stdout-rouge-fix' (located at /home/keith/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/stdout-rouge-fix.patch)
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #configuring 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #compiling 
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for ruby-1.8.7-p352 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #importing default gemsets (/home/keith/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.8.7-p352 - #complete 

$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > p "hello world"
"hello world"
 => nil 
1.8.7 :002 > ^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A^[[A
```

So in conclusion, I would be exceptionally grateful if some bright spark could suggest how I can debug this situation and resolve.

ps - Yes I have "Google" this problem to death....

Comment: And yes I have tried this patch in rvm: 

 https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/553

Comment: Show us your locale / keyboard layout

Comment: Have you tried 1.9.3?

I followed your instruction, and I was able to get the readline history to work properly.
Now, you are actually helpful in pointing out the right library "libreadline-dev".

Comment: Sweet Jebus, i've been banging my head off this for ages (previous solutions seeming to not work) and this did it for me this time.  Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so this might seem pretty obvious, well it always is when you know the answer:

I gave up using RVM, and switched to rbenv - which I'm very pleased I did!

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-readline-dir=/usr/include/readline --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local" rbenv-install 1.9.2-p290
```

This installed without error - and I'm still not convinced I need the gplv2 package as I've got libreadline6-dev installed. However that STILL didn't resolve my problem. It did remove RVM from the equation, and show me that despite my best efforts the IRB shell was refusing to use readline.

The answer came from reading through this great guide:

[RubyTools.pdf](http://java.ociweb.com/mark/RubyUserGroup/RubyTools.pdf)

Inside my ~/.irbrc file I found:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = false
```

A quick update to:

```
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true
```

And I'm cooking on gas!!

Thanks for all the great answers and suggestion, I do appreciate your time.

Answer (score 33):

Ubuntu 12.04 here:  the answers here helped, but were also misleading.

If you're using Ubuntu 12.04, DO NOT pkg install readline, with or without --skip-autoreconf.   After you've done that, either readline or zlib will be broken no matter what combination of switches you give to rvm install 1.9.3.

To get it to work, do the apt-get install that `rvm requirements` tells you to do, do a `pkg uninstall readline` and then do a simple `rvm remove 1.9.3; rvm install 1.9.3`

Comment: I tried to solve this problem more then 1 hr. Once applied your solution, everything started working properly. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 here also.

Tried everything on this page multiple times, then your solution.

Still not working, I'm getting mad at this. 

So I'm moving to setting up a new machine in virtualbox.

Comment: This worked for me as well, after I had tried all the others. Turns out I was missing a more than a few requirements.

Comment: I had a similar issue in 12.10 and this fixed it. I skipped the `pkg uninstall readline` which I am not exactly sure what it would do in Ubuntu

Comment: By "pkg uninstall readline" I think he means "rvm pkg uninstall readline". That being said, I skipped it too, and the remove/install still fixed the problem for me on 13.04.

Answer (score 12):

I struggled with this same issue with Ubuntu 11.10.

In my case readline would seemingly compile properly if I used the following:

```
$ rvm --skip-autoreconf pkg install readline
```

as outlined at the bottom of http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/

However, when I invoked irb, I would get the normal error "Unable to require readline"

Finally, based on Shane's command line, I invoked the following:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_usr_path
```

rather than the command mentioned at http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

In my case version 1.9.3 was what I wanted.  And *finally* irb came up with a functioning readline.

Thanks to everyone here for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

This solved my problem for rvm with Ruby 1.9.3

```
gem install rb-readline
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 12.04, this was all I needed to do. Also have the following in my ~/.irbrc, but not sure if it's required: `require 'irb/ext/save-history'
#History configuration
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"
IRB.conf[:USE_READLINE] = true`

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue but I'm on 11.04 and from reading the link you gave  https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/553 
and from the info in peplins comment there I removed the autoreconf call that was added here
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/commit/94c301d
and now readline compiles without any errors. I added back in the autoreconf call after I had compiled readline before installing ruby again.

So this is how I got it work:

edit ~/.rvm/scripts/functions/pkg and delete the following:

```
if [[ "${rvm_skip_autoreconf_flag:-0}" == 0 ]] &&
  which autoreconf >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
  which libtoolize >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
  [[ -f configure.ac || -f configure.in ]]
then
__rvm_run "$package/autoreconf" \
  "autoreconf -is --force" \
  "Prepare $package in $rvm_src_path/$package-$version."
fi
```

Compile readline and remove ruby (I used the ree_dependencies command but I'm not sure this is necessary):

```
rvm pkg install ree_dependencies
rvm remove 1.9.2
```

undo your deletion to ~/.rvm/scripts/functions/pkg
I then installed 1.9.2 with this command (again it's from the ree install which I'm not sure is necessary but this is what I used)

```
rvm install 1.9.2 --with-readline-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-zlib-dir=$rvm_usr_path --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_usr_path
```

and now all appears to work as it should, hope that helps someone.

Comment: Instead of editing `~/.rvm/scripts/functions/pkg`, you can use `rvm --skip-autoreconf pkg install readline`.

Answer (score 2):

My setup is ubuntu 11.10, RVM 1.10.2, ruby 1.9.3.

This readline problem was giving errors when running irb, and prevented running of the rails console due to the error:

> 'require': cannot load such file -- readline (LoadError)

The solution that worked for me was the one described by Bryan Larsen, i.e.

DO NOT pkg install readline, with or without --skip-autoreconf

Do the apt-get install that rvm requirements tells you to do, then

> rvm --skip-autoreconf pkg uninstall readline
>
> rvm remove 1.9.3
>
> rvm install 1.9.3

Thx for the tip Bryan.

Answer (score 2):

These steps fixed my problem (on a Lubuntu 12.04) after previously compiling ruby and continually getting the "compile readline missing" error anytime I ran:

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential openssl libreadline6 \
                      libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
                      libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
                      libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev \
                      automake libtool bison subversion
rvm pkg uninstall readline
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try a workarround installing the package **libreadline5-dev**.
I gess the **libreadline6-dev** is not working right now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of these worked for me. I ended up using the Quick Fix from http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/

That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it just worked out of the box with the latest verison of rvm. My steps

```
bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
```

according to `rvm requirements`:

```
apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion

rvm install 1.9.3

rvm
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget about everything that you hear about any logic, just look here and do the same step-by-step:

```
  (ubuntu x64):

 $ ruby extconf.rb 
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... no
checking for editline/readline.h... no

$ sudo aptitude install libedit-dev
..

$ ruby extconf.rb
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... no
checking for readline() in -ledit... yes
checking for rl_getc_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_completion_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_username_completion_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for rl_completion_matches() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_refresh_line() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for rl_deprep_term_function in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_append_character in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_attempted_completion_over in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_library_version in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_editing_mode in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_line_buffer in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_point in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_event_hook in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_catch_sigwinch in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_catch_signals in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_cleanup_after_signal() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for rl_clear_signals() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for rl_set_screen_size() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_get_screen_size() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_vi_editing_mode() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for rl_emacs_editing_mode() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for replace_history_entry() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... no
checking for remove_history() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for clear_history() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
creating Makefile
```

**anyway too much missing functions, but... do next**

```
$ rvm pkg uninstall readline
...
╰─○ ruby extconf.rb                                                    
checking for tgetnum() in -lncurses... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for readline() in -lreadline... yes
checking for rl_getc_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_completion_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_username_completion_function() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_matches() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_refresh_line() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_deprep_term_function in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_append_character in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_word_break_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_basic_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completer_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_filename_quote_characters in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_attempted_completion_over in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_library_version in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_editing_mode in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_line_buffer in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_point in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_event_hook in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_catch_sigwinch in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_catch_signals in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_cleanup_after_signal() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_clear_signals() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_set_screen_size() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_get_screen_size() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_vi_editing_mode() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_emacs_editing_mode() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for replace_history_entry() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for remove_history() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for clear_history() in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
checking for RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE in stdio.h,readline/readline.h,readline/history.h... yes
creating Makefile
$ make
compiling readline.c
linking shared-object readline.so
$ make install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 readline.so /home/sky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux
installing default readline libraries



irb
1.9.3-p194 :001 >
```

You can see it is work fine for me.

1 - don't forget to install libedit-dev

```
# dpkg --get-selections| egrep '(readline|libedit)'
libedit-dev                                     install # <= BSD PACKAGE, not GNU, but... it is work fine to me
libedit2                                        install # the same story as previous
libreadline-dev                                 install
libreadline5                                    install
libreadline6                                    install
libreadline6-dev                                install
readline-common                                 install
```

2 - uninstall pkg readline

```
$ rvm pkg uninstall readline
```

3 - go to **$rvm_path/src/ruby-#{version}/ext/readline** and do

```
$ ruby extconf.rb; make; make install
```

4 - forget about headache

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Bundler](http://bundler.io) then the following might help:

```
echo "gem 'rb-readline'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
```