# Ruby 1.9.3, RVM, readline won't install/compile

Tags: ruby, rvm, readline

I am running into the following error. I was using RVM with Ruby 1.9.2 and all worked perfect. I updated to ruby version 1.9.3 und now I am getting an load error when I try to use the irb.

```
/home/pabera/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 
`require': cannot load such file -- active_support (LoadError)
```

Actually I have all the readline packages installed (it worked fine with 1.9.2)

Now I tried several thinks, using **rvm pkg readline**. Doing this, I get the following output.

```
$ rvm pkg install readline
Fetching readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/pabera/.rvm/archives
Extracting readline-5.2.tar.gz to /home/pabera/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/pabera/.rvm/patches/readline-5.2/shobj-conf.patch'...
Prepare readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/pabera/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Compiling readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-5.2.
Installing readline to /home/pabera/.rvm/usr
Fetching readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/pabera/.rvm/archives
Extracting readline-6.2.tar.gz to /home/pabera/.rvm/src
Applying patch '/home/pabera/.rvm/patches/readline-6.2/patch-shobj-conf.diff'...
Prepare readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/pabera/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
Configuring readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Compiling readline in /home/pabera/.rvm/src/readline-6.2.
Installing readline to /home/pabera/.rvm/usr
```

I get the error in the middle, and I don't know how to fix it

```
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /home/pabera/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
```

My Autoconf.log output. Might this autoconf problem cause my issues? And yes, how would I fix thos missing templates then?

```
$ cat /home/pabera/.rvm/log/readline/autoreconf.log
[2012-03-19 10:07:03] autoreconf -is --force
autoheader: warning: missing template: CTYPE_NON_ASCII
autoheader: Use AC_DEFINE([CTYPE_NON_ASCII], [], [Description])
autoheader: warning: missing template: FIONREAD_IN_SYS_IOCTL
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_BSD_SIGNALS
autoheader: warning: missing template: HAVE_GETPW_DECLS
...
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoheader failed with exit status: 1
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you just need to re-install the appropriate gems as normal using `gem install`. Different rvm installations have different gem sets. What's the output of `gem list`?

Comment: `gem list` shows all my gems, `gem install` requires a gem name.. I am using bundler to setup my gems.. this works good - the rails server for example works great

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8201401/1062438
This helped and made it work for me..

Comment: What's the readline version installed on your system?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might forgot to use a ruby:

```
rvm use 1.9.3 --default
```

The default flag will tell rvm to use it for new terminals.

For using with projects (like rails):

```
cd projects/my-app
rvm use 1.9.3@my-app --rvmrc --create
```

Which will create a gemset `my-app` and project configuration file `.rvmrc` - now when you cd to that dir RVM wil swithc to that ruby@gemset.

There is very nice screencast showing basics of rvm usage: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

Comment: I don't know if this can do the job as well. I did it with the other method in my comment above..

Comment: from what you wrote in your question text is you have problem with using RVM, rest looks fine, even there was problem running autotool - readline was build and you are missing `active_support` - so there is problem with loading gem, and that happens most likely when you have default ruby but it is not used