# How to compile Ruby with Readline support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, readline

I'm running Linux Mint 15 which is based on Ubuntu 13.10.  I installed Ruby with RVM.  I'm trying to run Rails and I get the following error:

```
You're running a version of ruby with no Readline support
Please `gem install rb-readline` or recompile ruby --with-readline.
```

I tried every suggestion I found here on SO regarding this problem but I still get this error when trying to run `rails server`.  The suggested website for the fix http://beginrescueend.com/packages/readline/ is unavailable.

Comment: Go to https://rvm.io where the new site is.  It appears you are looking at older information.  Also don't hesitate to follow up on IRC chat room #RVM on http://freenode.net

Comment: open a bug report here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues for further investigation, rvm should have installed readline development headers and ruby should have used them

Answer (score 2):

For macOS: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X

```
RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Comment: also, if you want rbenv to always included the brewed readline on osx check out tpope's rbenv-readline plugin at https://github.com/tpope/rbenv-readline

Answer (score 0):

This was answered here for ubuntu/rvm combination: [How to get Readline support in IRB using RVM on Ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176076/how-to-get-readline-support-in-irb-using-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-10)

I use chruby/ruby-build for the task, with ruby-build it can be done just like that(you can install it even to rvm folder):

```
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir=/your/readline/headers/path
ruby-build 2.0.0 ~/.rvm/rubies/
```