# Cannot launch Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rvm

Rails console doesn't work on my production server. Here is what happens:

```
root@myapp:/webapps/myapp/current# rails c
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails/gems/rails-3.0.5/bin/rails:8:in `rescue in <main>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails/gems/rails-3.0.5/bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Previously I was getting Readline related error, explained here: [Problems with the rails console, RVM and readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498919/problems-with-the-rails-console-rvm-and-readline)

I tried the propsoed fix, and now I'm not getting readline error. Still the console won't launch.

Here is the rvm info output:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux 111items 2.6.38-linode31 #1 SMP Mon Mar 21 21:22:33 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.1.5(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.13.4 () by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "53 minutes 38 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p194"
    date:         "2012-04-20"
    platform:     "i686-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-04-20 revision 35410"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Locally I was always able to launch rails console, but on the remote machine something is different.

upd: My best guess so far is that Rails is missing correct path to "rails/cli". Have to research and see how this can be fixed.

Comment: Was it intended to run `rails c` using the root user?

Comment: Does it affect Rails console?

Comment: Not sure. I am just suggesting as a part of the debugging process :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again with a normal user, after installing RVM as a normal user.
Installing RVM as *root* is a pain as far as I experienced, I particularly had paths issues.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I managed to solve this basically by updating rvm, ruby, and creating new gemset. Also thanks for hint about normal user, have to do this properly at some point. I have the rails console now working under root :D

Answer (score 0):

If that won't work you can always switch to rbenv. It is lighter and have everything you need on a localhost