# rails server in debug mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

When I try to run rails server in debugger mode using "rails server --debugger". I am getting the following error on my console.

```
/home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Debugger::LocalInterface::Readline (NameError)
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:53:in `each'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:53:in `block in initialize'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/interface.rb:52:in `initialize'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:61:in `new'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug/processor.rb:61:in `initialize'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:9:in `new'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:9:in `<module:Debugger>'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/ruby-debug19-0.11.6/cli/ruby-debug.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/rack/debugger.rb:9:in `initialize'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:295:in `new'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:295:in `block in build_app'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:291:in `reverse_each'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:291:in `build_app'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

RubyGems Environment

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [i686-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/navyug/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

  - ruby
  - x86-linux
- GEM PATHS:

  - /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - /home/navyug/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :benchmark => false
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 0):

I think the Readline package is missing in your setup. Since you are using RVM, try and install the readline package via rvm. These links might be helpful:

- [Previous similar SO question related to readline problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498919/problems-with-the-rails-console-rvm-and-readline)
- [Fixing Readline for the Ruby on Rails console](http://vvv.tobiassjosten.net/ruby-on-rails/fixing-readline-for-the-ruby-on-rails-console)
- [RVM package: Readline](https://rvm.io/packages/readline/)

Comment: For OSX, this is an excellent guide: https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X