# Rails 3.2 debugger up key and down key is not working in Ubuntu 12

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-12.04, ruby-debug

I have just installed rails in ubuntu 12 and I installed all its dependencies and gems required all project is running flowently . Only one thing I am really missing this time is ruby debugger is not 100% working in it.

I don't know where I am doing wrong.

Same gems were installed in my ubuntu 11.10. and on debugging up arrow key and down arrow key was working properly to fetch previous comments.

Normally rails developer use up/down key for previous command fetch/edit/re-run. But I don't know why is it not working this time.

But this time Rails 3.2 debugger up key and down key is not working in Ubuntu 12 this time. Have anyone face this issue before?

Comment: I would suggest to change the title of you question , because it seems you are asking about the Rails console .

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to check your system's readline tools , like this :

```
apt-cache policy ncurses-dev
```

and if it's not installed : `apt-get install ncurses-dev` .

After that you should include changes in your Ruby :

```
cd $HOME/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p0/ext/readline
ruby extconf.rb -- --with-readline-dir="$HOME/.rvm/usr"
make install
```

Here is a [helpful discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498919/problems-with-the-rails-console-rvm-and-readline) on topic .